# Vanishing at infinity implies uniform continuity

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space. Then each $f\in C_0(X)$ is uniformly continuous.

The first steps are clear. For fixed $\epsilon>0$ we take a compact $K$ such that $|f|<\epsilon$ outside of $K$. $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, hence we find $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ for $x,y\in K$.
Now the only problem is what to do if $|x-y|<\delta$ with $x\notin K, y\in K$. It is not guaranteed that there is a point $z$ of the boundary of $K$ nearby such that we can estimate $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(z)|+|f(z)-f(y)|$.

Can you help me?

Comment: Tim, for every $x \in K$ there is an $\eta(x) > 0$ such that $\lvert f(y) - f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $y$ with $d(y,x) < \eta(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the hint. If i take $\eta$ as the supremum over all possible $\eta$ the property stays valid. If I can show now that $\eta$ is continuous, I am finished. I will try to do that now.

Comment: Wait, it's easier just using the definition of compactness for the collection of $B(x,\eta(x))$, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This answer builds on Daniel Fischer's hint.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, take some compact $K$ such that $|f|  <  \epsilon/2$ on $X\setminus K$.
Then:

$\quad(1)$: There is some $\delta_1 > 0$ such that whenever $x,y \in K$ satisfy $|x-y|<\delta_1$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.
This follows from the fact that continuous function are uniformly continuous on compact sets.

$\quad(2)$: Whenever $x,y\in X\setminus K$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)|\leqslant |f(x)|  + |f(y)| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

---

Now, for each $x\in K$, the continuity of $f$ implies there is $\rho_x>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $|x-y|<\rho_x$.

The open balls $B\left(x;\frac12\rho_x\right)$ cover $K$, so by compacity there must be some finite subcover

$$K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \, B\left(x_i;\frac12\rho_{x_i}\right).$$

Let $\delta_2 = \frac12\min\{\rho_{x_i}\,|\,i=1,\dots,n\}$.

Suppose $x\in K$ and $y\in X\setminus K$ are such that $|x-y|<\delta_2$.
There is some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $x \in B\left(x_i;\frac12\rho_{x_i}\right)$, that is, $|x-x_i|<\frac12\rho_{x_i}$.
Then

$$|x_i - y|\leqslant |x_i - x| + |x - y| < \frac12\rho_{x_i} + \delta_2 \leqslant \rho_{x_i},$$

and hence

$$|f(x) - f(y)|\leqslant |f(x)-f(x_i)|+|f(x_i)-f(y)| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.$$

---

Together with $(1)$ and $(2)$, the argument above shows that whenever $x,y \in X$ satisfy $|x-y|<\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, they also satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.
In other words, $f$ is uniformly continuous, as we set out to prove. $\square$

Comment: +1 For the detailed answer, but let me note that your argument why the supremum in the definition of $\delta_2$ exists in $\mathbb R$ is a bit strange. You build the supremum of a finite subset of $\mathbb R$, so it is clearly a maximum.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like you should actually take the minimum. Otherwise your inequality $\frac12\eta_{x_i} + \delta_2 < \eta_{x_i}$ (which relies on $\delta_2<\frac12\eta_{x_i}$ is wrong. Moreover, I don't see where you make use of $\eta_x\le1$. So, we should be able to stay with $\rho_x$.

Comment: You are right, I must've been tired when I wrote it out. Thank you for the observations, it should be fixed now.